# Typing into lookup field before new form finishes loading doesn't work as expected - crm 2011 online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

We have  a custom entity. When you create a new instance of this entity, it is defined such that the field that receives the initial focus is a lookup field of type customer.

When using outlook client, *create a new email, set regarding, custom entity, new*
and while the new form is loading, if you start typing, various bad things happen including in some instances outlook crashing.

Looking into this, I noticed that if I use the web client and again, *custom entity, new* and start typing before the new form loads, while I can't crash IE, it doesn't work as expected. Sometimes it will lose some of typing and other times IE will get confused, spin it's wheels for a bit and eventually come back with some generic error message.

The problem seems to be when typing into a lookup field before the form has finished loading. The incident entity also loads with a lookup field having the focus with the same result. I've updated outlook and IE with latest patches etc.

While one obvious answer is to wait for the form to load, I have been tasked with seeing if there is any other way around this. Has anyone run into this or have any ideas? The only thing I can think of is to add a text field to the entity such that it gets the initial focus and onchange, pretend it is a customer lookup and populate the real field accordingly. This seems like an awful hack hence this email asking for ideas!

Comment: You're correct, I've tried and it really did crash!
Why? I think because the **DOm** isn't ready to receive user's action.
You have to until the form completely loads all its ribbon and elements on the form.

Comment: @Anwar good to know you can replicate it. I think it's fair to say it's a bug in that it shouldn't crash and hopefully a fix for it will appear in some future rollup. In the meantime I'm wondering if there's any way within crm to somehow work around it.

Answer (score 0):

MS confirmed that this was a bug and it has been fixed in a subsequent CRM Outlook addin rollup. Can't remember which one...